# 3D curve fitting in OCTAVE

Tags: octave

I was using octave polyfit to give me the best fit function for a 2D graph but now I will have to start handling 3D data and I can't find any function that do the same as polyfit but when you have 2 variables instead of just one. I know that in matlab you can use the curve fitting tool box, anyone knows if there is something equivalent for octave? Or any octave command that I can use to find a function that best fits a 3D graph?

Please, please, please! I am starting to get desperate as I REAALLY don't wanna pay for matlab T.T

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can use *interp2* for two dimensional dependence (3D graphs). Read octave documentation about [multidimensional interpolation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Multi_002ddimensional-Interpolation.html).
Another option is *griddata* for [scattered data](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Interpolation-on-Scattered-Data.html#Interpolation-on-Scattered-Data).

Comment: interpolation and fitting are close, but not just the same.